# ruby - require & cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm new to ruby and I have a problem loading gems.
I've read every topic about this on SO but I couldn't figure out how to make it work :/
I'm on a fresh install of Ruby 1.9.3 and RubyGems 1.8.11

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: D:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: D:/dev/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: D:/dev/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - D:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - D:/aoi/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I've installed the gem twice, once from command line

```
gem install soap4r
```

And second time i've tried to use RubyMine installer, but the result where the same,
when I try to

```
require 'rubygems'
resuire 'soap'
```

The output is the same :

```
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- soap
        from D:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from D:/dev/Ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get this https://github.com/spox/soap4r-spox and patch your ruby with it, its the default soap module for ruby but was pulled out of 1.9 versions

Comment: thanks, i'll get that one for sure instead of using the Gem, but the problem I have it's with every installed gem, not only soap4r (I just took that one as example)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to the top of your file:

```
gem 'soap4r'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
```

Or as an alternative try [Savon](http://savon.rubiii.com/)

Comment: worked great, but do I have to do this for every single external Gem i'll be using ? (I have the same file not found problem on every gem installed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you do not run multiple different ruby versions ? Then your gems are not bound to the correct ruby version.

Moreover, I notice something strange :

> http://rubygems.org/gems/soap : "This gem has been yanked, but it is still available for download for other gems that may have depended on it"

On the contrary, there seems to be another more interesting gem around : soap4r.

There is a [tuto](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_services.htm) here. I especially noticed that sort of lines :

> require "soap/rpc/standaloneserver"

That means "require soap" may not be sufficient in your case.