# `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rvm, require

So I realize that this is an over asked question, but I can't seem to figure out the answer. I've already referenced these question and answers:

[ruby - require & cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454742/ruby-require-cannot-load-such-file)
[Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

Basically I'm writing a gem and when I try to require another file with a class inside the main module it throws this error ``require': cannot load such file` When I give the full path and file extension it works. I've read that you should use require './dir/filename' . This doesn't work either.

It should be noted that I have single user rvm installed and `which ruby` yields `/Users/davidhahn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 1):

In 1.9, I'd recommend using require_relative for files inside of your library, as it always uses the relative path from the current file, as opposed to the load path. In < 1.9, you have to make sure that your root (usually `lib` in gems) is in the load path, and that a different library does not change the order on you.